# xargs with stdin/stdout redirection

Tags: io-redirection, xargs

I would like to run:

```
./a.out < x.dat > x.ans
```

for each **.dat* file in the directory *A*.

Sure, it could be done by bash/python/whatsoever script, but I like to write sexy one-liner. All I could reach is (still without any stdout):

```
ls A/*.dat | xargs -I file -a file ./a.out
```

But *-a* in xargs doesn't understand replace-str 'file'.

Thank you for help.

Comment: In addition to the other good answers here, you can use the -a option of GNU xargs.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all, **[do not use `ls` output as a file list](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**. Use shell expansion or `find`. See below for potential consequences of *ls+xargs* misuse and an example of proper `xargs` usage.

#### 1. Simple way: *for* loop

If you want to process just the files under `A/`, then a simple `for` loop should be enough:

```
for file in A/*.dat; do ./a.out < "$file" > "${file%.dat}.ans"; done
```

---

#### 2.<sub>pre1</sub> Why not   `ls | xargs` ?

Here's an example of how bad things may turn if you use `ls` with `xargs` for the job. Consider a following scenario:

- first, let's create some empty files:

  ```
  $ touch A/mypreciousfile.dat\ with\ junk\ at\ the\ end.dat
  $ touch A/mypreciousfile.dat
  $ touch A/mypreciousfile.dat.ans
  ```
- see the files and that they contain nothing:

  ```
  $ ls -1 A/
  mypreciousfile.dat
  mypreciousfile.dat with junk at the end.dat
  mypreciousfile.dat.ans

  $ cat A/*
  ```
- run a magic command using `xargs`:

  ```
  $ ls A/*.dat | xargs -I file sh -c "echo TRICKED > file.ans"
  ```
- the result:

  ```
  $ cat A/mypreciousfile.dat
  TRICKED with junk at the end.dat.ans

  $ cat A/mypreciousfile.dat.ans
  TRICKED
  ```

So you've just managed to overwrite both `mypreciousfile.dat` and `mypreciousfile.dat.ans`. If there were any content in those files, it'd have been erased.

---

#### 2. Using  `xargs` : the proper way with  `find`

If you'd like to insist on using `xargs`, use `-0` (null-terminated names) :

```
find A/ -name "*.dat" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I file sh -c './a.out < "file" > "file.ans"'
```

Notice two things:

1. this way you'll create files with `.dat.ans` ending;
2. this **will break** if some file name contains a quote sign (`"`).

Both issues can be solved by different way of shell invocation:

```
find A/ -name "*.dat" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 bash -c './a.out < "$0" > "${0%dat}ans"'
```

---

#### 3. All done within `find ... -exec`

```
 find A/ -name "*.dat" -type f -exec sh -c './a.out < "{}" > "{}.ans"' \;
```

This, again, produces `.dat.ans` files and will break if file names contain `"`. To go about that, use `bash` and change the way it is invoked:

```
 find A/ -name "*.dat" -type f -exec bash -c './a.out < "$0" > "${0%dat}ans"' {} \;
```

Comment: +1 for mentionning not to parse the output of ls.

Comment: Option 2 breaks when the filenames contains ".

Comment: Very good point, thanks! I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I want just mention, that if `zsh` is used as shell (and SH_WORD_SPLIT is not set), all the nasty special cases (white spaces, " in the filename etc.) need not to be considered. The trivial `for file in A/*.dat; do ./a.out < $file > ${file%.dat}.ans ; done` works in all cases.

Comment: -1 because I'm trying to figure out how to do xargs with stdin and my question has nothing to do with files or `find`.

Answer (score 3):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ./a.out "<{} >{.}.ans" ::: A/*.dat
```

Added bonus: You get the processing done in parallel.

Watch the intro videos to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: You are the author parallel, so this falls under self-promotion without a disclaimer. Also, I don't like how Parallel lies to users about calling it with a flag to accept an agreement, but then prompts for additional input. Until you remove that, I doubt your software will receive widespread adoption. It's also annoying because I can't use it cleanly on a VM/container.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Thanks for your input. You can read the background on http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/doc/citation-notice-faq.txt (TL;DR: The goal is not widespread adoption, but long term survival).

Comment: I see. I've tried your software and it worked fine, but I wasn't comfortable with the `--citation` (although I can certainly relate to your predicament). Despite your understandable desire for citations, it feels very non-GNU to force the command. My primary complaint was that it didn't work as described: it clearly says that you can run "parallel --citation" to never see the warning again, but that isn't true! You then need to manually enter something. I felt deceived and uninstalled it.

Comment: @EntangledLoops check how debian solved it, there was no long quarrel about it.
after all parallel is open source, so you can remove the citation warning. It is indeed something I've not seen with any other GNU tool before.
In general it's a well working tool, I prefer xargs for simplicity in most cases but sometimes parallel comes handy.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this (syntax may vary a bit depending on the shell you use):

`$ for i in $(find A/ -name \*.dat); do ./a.out < ${i} > ${i%.dat}.ans; done`

Comment: That would not work. It would try to operate on stuff like `somefile.dat.dat` and redirect all output to a single file.

Comment: You're right. I edited the solution to correct it.

Comment: OK - Almost good :) Just `somefile.dat.ans` output stuff would look not so nice.

Comment: Edited! I did not know about '%'. It works like a charm, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Adding a `-type file` would be nice (can't `< directory`), and this makes the unusual-filename-fairy sad.

Comment: *Y*U*C*K*. Always assume find's result is: a) HUGE (enough that shell will refuse to expand it) and b) contains SPACES (there is unfortunately no way to deal with newlines, but those are not common, spaces are). If you had `for i in A/*.dat`, that would be another matter.

Answer (score 2):

For simple patterns, the for loop is appropriate:

```
for file in A/*.dat; do
    ./a.out < "${file}" > "${file%.dat}.ans" # Never forget the QUOTES!
done
```

For more complex cases where you need another utility to list the files (zsh or bash 4 have powerful enough patterns that you rarely need find, but if you want to stay within POSIX shell or use fast shell like dash, you will need find for anything non-trivial), while read is most appropriate:

```
find A -name '*.dat' -print | while IFS= read -r file; do
   ./a.out < "${file}" > "${file%.dat}.ans" # Never forget the QUOTES!
done
```

This will handle spaces, because read is (by default) line-oriented. It will not handle newlines and it will not handle backslashes, because by default it interprets escape sequences (that actually allows you to pass in a newline, but find can't generate that format). Many shells have `-0` option to read so in those you can handle all characters, but unfortunately it's not POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to complicate it. You could do it with a `for` loop:

```
for file in A/*.dat; do
  ./a.out < "$file" >"${file%.dat}.ans"
done
```

the `${file%.dat}.ans` bit will remove the `.dat` filename suffix from the filename in `$file` and instead add `.ans` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need at least a shell invocation in the xargs:

```
ls A/*.dat | xargs -I file sh -c "./a.out < file > file.ans"
```

**Edit: It should be noted that this approach does not work when the filenames contain whitespace.** Can't work. Even if you used find -0 and xargs -0 to make xargs understand the spaces correctly, the -c shell call would croak on them. However, the OP explicitely asked for an xargs solution, and this is the best xargs solution I came up with. **If whitespace in filenames might be an issue, use find -exec or a shell loop.**

Comment: Have a look at [why it is a bad idea to parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: In general, sure, but I assume someone trying to do xargs voodoo knows this. Since these filenames undergo another shell expansion, they have to be well-behaved anyway.

Comment: You are wrong about the shell expansion. `ls` outputs things like spaces without escaping and **that** is the problem.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Yes, I understand that problem. Now just suppose you would properly escape these spaces and get them into xargs: They are replaced in sh's -c string, sh tokenizes the -c string, and everything breaks.

Comment: Yes. You see now, parsing `ls` is no good. But `xargs` *can* be safely used with find - see the suggestion No 2 in my answer.