# remove special character from files in directory

Tags: files, directory

I need to remove special characters from all .htm files in a directory.
Ideally I need to keep the file name but if I have to I can copy each file to 1 or something like that.
Here is the command I need to run on each file:  tr '\015' '\n' < $filename > $filename.1

Comment: Where is the problem? Apparently you know what you need to run.

Comment: I don't know how to do the for loop or the xargs to run that command on every file in directory ... and I don't know how to run that command and keep the same file name

Comment: In bash: ```for file in /dir/* 
do
  your command
done```

Comment: it doesn't work ... I get ambiguous redirect error

Comment: and if I try this    ls *.htm | xargs -i tr '\015' '\n' < {} > {}_1     then I get back:  -bash: {}: No such file or directory

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/xargs-with-stdin-stdout-redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what OS and interpreter you use, but this works for me on Debian/Bash:

```
for file in *.htm; do
  tr "\044" "\n" < $file > $file.1;
done
```